# Maven Assembly plugin: useTransitiveDependencies not working?

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

In my assembly descriptor I have the following:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>ext</outputDirectory>
         <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>group1:artifact1:jar:${pom.version}</exclude>
            <exclude>group2:artifact2:jar:${pom.version}</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

When running *mvn dependency:tree* I get the following for example:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
```

What I wanna achieve is that I ONLY have *string-context* in my *ext* folder.  When setting *useTransitiveDependencies* as above the *ext* directory does NOT exist at all and when removing the property I have ALL thress jars in my *ext* folder.

Anyone knows how I can exclude *spring-aop* and *aopalliance*?

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Set the `useTransitiveFiltering` to `true`. If you use the `include`/`exclude` inside `dependencySet` you should consider this option.

Comment: This saved me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that spring-context should be for you, not a transitive dependency, but a direct dependency.

If you accept to allow transitive dependencies, you delegate the choice of the dependencies to be included to the dependencies POM.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple entry in the assembly descriptor:

```
      <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
```

which should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

> Anyone knows how I can exclude spring-aop and aopalliance?

With:

```
<exclude>org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE</exclude>
<exclude>aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0</exclude>
```

Comment: Yes, I now how to exclude them manually but these two are just an example and my depedency:tree contains about 100 transitive dependencies.Plus I do not wanna have to think abut adding excludes here every time you add a new dependency to your project.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try running this maven command with debug flag? Please run it with debug flag , you will find a solution.